# json array parsing in c

Tags: c, arrays, json, parsing

i am trying to parse a json array,i am facing problem.

My array is like this:

```
configure: {
  "id": 4,
  "userId": 107,
  "deviceMacAddress": "00:06:66:30:02:3C",
  "medication": [{
    "id": 11,
    "version": 18,
    "name": "name1",
    "unit": "mg",
    "forMed": "for1",
    "schedule": [1]
  }, {
  "id": 45,
  "version": 1,
  "name": "sdga",,
  "unit": "mg",
  "forMed": "54234",
  "schedule": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  }],
```

i am able to access medication array and print total array,but not able to access objects inside array.
can you pls suggest any solution or any example to do this using C language?

MyCode

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct json_object *med_obj, *medi_obj, *tmp1_obj;
  struct array_list *lArray;
  charname[10] = {0};
  static const char filename[] = "xyz.txt";
  med_obj = json_object_from_file(filename);
  medi_obj = json_object_object_get(med_obj, "medication");
  lArray = json_object_get_array(medi_obj);
  tmp1_obj = json_object_object_get(medi_obj, "name");
  strcpy (name,json_object_to_json_string(tmp1_obj));
  printf("name=%s\n",name);
}
```

Regards,
Lenin.

Comment: Can we see what you have coded so far to help advise you on where to move forward?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: MyCode:       int main(int argc, char **argv){
struct json_object*med_obj,*medi_obj,*tmp1_obj;
struct array_list *lArray;
charname[10]={0};                                                   static const char filename[] = "xyz.txt";
med_obj=json_object_from_file(filename);                            medi_obj = json_object_object_get(med_obj, "medication");
lArray=json_object_get_array(medi_obj);
tmp1_obj = json_object_object_get(medi_obj, "name");
strcpy (name,json_object_to_json_string(tmp1_obj));
printf("name=%s\n",name);

Comment: Hi i have put my code, can you please check and suggest any solution?

Comment: @Aiias i have put my code,can you pls check and suggest any solution.

Comment: @leninT.mohan - Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to access the inner array using a `json_object *` variable.

Try this:

```
struct json_object *med_obj, *medi_array, *medi_array_obj, *medi_array_obj_name;
int arraylen, i;
charname[10] = {0};
static const char filename[] = "xyz.txt";
med_obj = json_object_from_file(filename);
medi_array = json_object_object_get(med_obj, "medication");

// medi_array is an array of objects
arraylen = json_object_array_length(medi_array);

for (i = 0; i < arraylen; i++) {
  // get the i-th object in medi_array
  medi_array_obj = json_object_array_get_idx(medi_array, i);
  // get the name attribute in the i-th object
  medi_array_obj_name = json_object_object_get(medi_array_obj, "name");
  // print out the name attribute
  printf("name=%s\n", json_object_get_string(medi_array_obj_name));
}
```

Comment: Thanks aiias,it's working.I am facing new issue whenever trying to access an object in array(eg:name in my case)all the values with name are printing.I want only particular values.can you pls suggest any solution.Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @Aiias while printing an object (eg:name in my array)iam getting all the values with name,i want to print only certain values with name tag.    can you pls suggest any solution

Comment: @leninT.mohan - What do you mean by you are getting `all the values with name`? Currently we are looping through the array. If you only want the first object in the array, don't use a `for` loop and instead just do `medi_array_obj = json_object_array_get_idx(medi_array, 0);`

Comment: Hi @Aiias iwant all the object values but i have to print each value in different line(i.e "name" =1 in line1,next occurence of object "name" in array in second line and so on upto 10 times).Now when i am printing they are printing in a single line.How can i read all the objects in same way and print them?pls check my code in my earlier posts. Thanks for you reply

Comment: @leninT.mohan - Are you saying that `printf("name = %s \n", json_object_get_string(medi_array_obj_name));` does not print out multiple lines? The `"\n"` newline character should break to the next line. Try adding a space between the `=` and then `\n`.

Comment: No Aiias i wanted to access one object in array at a time,but when i tried to print name it is printing all the values in a single line.I wanted to access only particular object values.Now i have done it already.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @leninT.mohan - If this post answers your question, I would recommend marking it as the answer as it could help people in the future that come across similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jsoncpp to do this job.
Array as a Json::Value, you can

```
medicationValue = jsonObject[medicationKey];
Json::Value::Members member;
member = medicationValue .getMemberNames();

for (Json::Value::Members::iterator iter = member.begin(); iter != member.end(); iter++) {
    the element of medication here
}
```

I hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the array as a json object, you should get it as a json_object* but not a array_list*

```
struct json_object *lArray; 
...
lArray=json_object_get(medi_obj); 
tmp1_obj = json_object_object_get(json_object_array_get_idx(lArray, 0), "name");
```